# Is the HttpContext.Current disposed even if an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, datacontext, idisposable

The reason I ask is because the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection seems like it would be a good place to put `IDisposable` objects such as a `DataContext` so that a Repository might access it transparently without having to to inject any dependencies related to a specific ORM technology into the Repository. This would also allow the repository to decide whether to engage in a `UnitOfWork` or take on the additional responsibility of actually persisting any changes.

For example:

The Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(...)
{
   Items[KeyValueFromConfigurationFile] = new DataContext();
   var repo = new Repository();
   var rootEntity = repo.GetById(1);
}
```

The Repository:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
   var ctx = HttpContext.Current.Items[KeyValueFromConfigurationFile] as DataContext;
   return ctx.TEntities.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

Of course, I would check for nulls and perform the steps needed to get a `DataContext` if it wasn't available in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection.

So, back to my original question given the above code: **Will the `HttpContext.Current` be disposed along with any of the objects contained in its Items collection even if an exception is thrown?**

Answer (score 14):

Objects in HttpContext.Current.Items will not automatically be disposed. You would need to handle this yourself. You can do it in the global.asax Application_EndRequest:

```
            foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Items.Values)
            {
                var disposableItem = item as IDisposable;

                if (disposableItem != null)
                {
                    disposableItem.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. One thing people should note is how often EndRequest is fired. In this thread http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=1558~-1 . The  Visual Studio Web Server fires this event for all HTTP requests (including images, css, etc), while IIS only fires during .NET handled pages. Keep that in mind if you're debugging in VS Web Server and you see the event fired over and over.

Comment: `foreach (var v in HttpContext.Current.Items.Values.OfType<IDisposable>()) v.Dispose();`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think there was an issue with the last post providing a solution because the underlying collection isn't being modified, which cannot be done while it's being enumerated, but I did recently run into sporadic errors with this code.  We were seeing the error 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute' when OnEndRequest fired and executed the for loop below:

```
        foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Items.Values)
        {
            var disposableItem = item as IDisposable;

            if (disposableItem != null)
            {
                disposableItem.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

So apparently disposing the current HttpContext items while iterating the collection with a foreach loop can also pose a problem.  There's a couple ways around this, but I chose to do it this way:

```
        int size = HttpContext.Current.Items.Count;
        if (size > 0)
        {
            var keys = new object[size];
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                var obj = HttpContext.Current.Items[keys[i]] as IDisposable;
                if (obj != null)
                    obj.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is right, somehow the collection gets modified and I'm not sure about the reason. Normally, the dispose call shouldn't affect the collection. Maybe some other thread changes the collection at the same time (Application_EndRequest fires on a different thread than Application_BeginRequest, and is after/concurrent with the time the response is sent to the client)